# Symfony 5 event listener not registered

Tags: symfony, exception, events, listener, registration

Based on the [given example in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener), I am unable to see my kernel exception event listener registered.
It does not appear with the console debug command:

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher
```

Of course, no error, no warning, and the method is not called.

```
// src/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the trick/trap:
**Order in services.yaml is very important!**

Before (does not work):

```
App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, priority: 1000 }

App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
        - '../src/Tests/'
```

After (it works!):

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
        - '../src/Tests/'

App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, priority: 1000 }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  If you have your listener implement the EventSubscriberInterface then you won't need any services.yaml configuration at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude **EventListener** directory path from Automatic Service Loading.

```
# config/services.yaml
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/EventListener/' # <--- HERE
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
        - '../src/Tests/'
```